# Verificar se o codigo existe em outro site (remote extract)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, libcurl

Boa tarde galera!

Estou precisando, verificar um código existente em outros sites.. tipo um widget a pessoa vai copia meu código e coloca no site dela, dai eu preciso verificar se esse código existe no site dela antes de fazer o cadastro!

Ainda não  tenho nenhum código, alguém pode me ajudar?

Consigo localizar está tag dentro do código HTML

```
<!--NOMEDOMEUSITE-->
```

se eu identificar esta parte, quer dizer q o usuário tem o código no site, alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso de inúmeras formas bem simples. Nesta resposta vou citar duas.

- PHP puro
- Javascipt com ajax `jQuery`

---

**PHP puro** (com `file_get_contents` e `strpos`)

```php
<?php

/**
 * Url do site a ser consultado
 * Ex: https://dominio/rota
 */
$site = '<INSIRA A URL DO SITE AQUI>';

/**
 * A função file_get_contents
 * retorna o código fonte da página como um string
 */
$html = file_get_contents($site);

/**
 * Aqui seria a string que você quer checkar se está no site
 * Ex: <!--NOMEDOMEUSITE-->
 */
$search = "<!--NOMEDOMEUSITE-->";

/**
 * Agora que o html é uma string
 * Podemos checar se ela contém
 * o termo que você precisa
 *
 * Nota: strpos retorna a 
 * posição da string encontrada ou false
 * caso ele não encontre
 */
$pos = strpos($html, $search);


/**
 * Note o operador tripo "!=="
 * como strpos pode retornar valores
 * não booleanos que são interpretados como false
 * Esse operador irá checar se o valor $pos é false
 * e ainda se ele é do tipo boolean.
 */
if ($pos !== false) {
    echo "encontrou";
}
else {
    echo "não encontrou";
}
```

---

**Com javascript** (com `jQuery $.get` e `indexOf`)

```js
$.get('<URL A SER VERIFICADA>', function (html) {   
    /**
     * Aqui seria a string que você quer checkar se está no site
     * Ex: <!--NOMEDOMEUSITE-->
     */
    var search = "<!--NOMEDOMEUSITE-->";


    /**
     * Agora que o html é uma string
     * Podemos checar se ela contém
     * o termo que você precisa
     *
     * Nota: indexOf() retorna a 
     * posição da string encontrada ou -1
     * caso ele não encontre
     */
    var pos = html.indexOf(search);

    /**
     * Basta verificar o valor de pos
     * e fazer o que precisar
     */
    if ( pos > -1 ) {
        alert( "encontrou" );
    }
    else {
        alert( "não encontrou" );
    }

});
```

**IMPORTANTE**

Existem 2 casos onde você não conseguirá fazer essa checagem diretamente. São Eles:

1. Se o usuário inserir o seu widget via algum gerenciador de tags (como o Google TagManager por exemplo) pois o widget será inserido via js no lado do usuário (cliente).
2. Se o usuário inserir seu widget no código fonte de uma página em uma área restrita (protegida por login e senha) no site dele.

**Leituras relacionadas**

- PHP [file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-get-contents.php)
- PHP [str_pos](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strpos.php)
- jQuery [$.get](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)
- Javascript [indexOf](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp)

Comment: Obrigado! deu certo

Answer (score 0):

O melhor método é usar uma instância dedicada do [NodeIterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/NodeIterator) iterando todos os comentários contidos em um dado elemento da página.

> NodeIterator (IE >= 9)

```js
function filterNone() {
  return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
}

function cleanString(str) {
  return str.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, '');
}

function getAllComments(rootElem) {
  let comments = [];
  let iterator = document.createNodeIterator(rootElem, NodeFilter.SHOW_COMMENT, filterNone, false);
  let curNode;
  while (curNode = iterator.nextNode()) {
    comments.push(curNode.nodeValue);
  }
  return comments;
}

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  let myWebSite = 'meuSiteSuperNice.com';
  let allComments = getAllComments(document.body);
  let theyHaveMyWebSite = allComments.find(item => cleanString(item) === cleanString(myWebSite));

  if (theyHaveMyWebSite) {
    alert('Eles tem meu web site')
  } else {
    alert('Triste! Nao tem meu web site')
  };
});
```

```html
<!-- 1 comentario -->

<!-- 2 comentario -->

<!-- 3 comentario -->

<!-- meuSiteSuperNice.com -->

<!-- 4 comentario -->
```

**Entretanto, não é uma boa abordagem usar a [tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/) de comentário `<!--...-->` para esse propósito**. Iterar todos os comentários contidos numa página pode ter um consumo extremamente alto dos recursos computacionais.

A tag [meta](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp) é a mais indicada para seu propósito (Podes ler sobre isso [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6096741/which-elements-will-load-first-in-an-html-page)).

```js
function cleanString(str) {
  return str.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, '');
}

let meta = document.querySelectorAll('meta[property^="testeSite:on"]')[0].getAttribute("content");
let myWebSite = 'meuSiteSuperNice.com';

if (cleanString(myWebSite) === cleanString(meta)) {
  alert('Eles tem meu web site')
} else {
  alert('Triste! Nao tem meu web site')
};
```

```html
<head>


  <title>Site deles</title>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta property="testeSite:on" content="meuSiteSuperNice.com" />

</head>
```